# How to drag view with two finger

Tags: iphone, view, drag, gesture

Hi all:
       I want to write a gesture recognizer on the iphone, that I cold use two finger to drag the view. Just like we use two finger on the MacBook Pro's touch pad. 
       If the view's size is larger than the window's size of the device, I could use two finger to drag the view. is there any good way to solve it ?

(Thanks enamrik and Naveen Thunga.   I achieved my goal just now, but there is a new question that how could I know the UILongPressGestureRecognizer is over. I want call a method and set some value when my finger leaves the screen of my iphone.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UILongPressGestureRecognizer class has a numberOfTouchesRequired property you might find useful

Answer (score 0):

Use uigesturerecognizer's properties and enable View's multitouch property. See some sample on UIGestureRecognizer that may help you.